# Spark Cannot detect ES version - AWS OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

I'm trying read my data from AWS OpenSearch domain and getting this error: "Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only".

When I'm connecting to a domain under ElasticSearch (version 7.10), everything is fine.

My sample Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_json,col}

object SparkContextApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val appName = "App"
      val master = "local[*]"
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
        .setMaster(master)
        .set("es.nodes", "https://*************************.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com")
        .set("es.port", "***")
        .set("es.http.timeout", "5m")
        .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
        .set("es.net.ssl", "true")
        .set("es.net.http.auth.user", "********")
        .set("es.net.http.auth.pass", "********")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val data = sc.esRDD("***/***")
     }
  }
```

The library dependencies:
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12" % "8.2.3"

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue, did you ever find the solution to this ? I'm using version `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.17.3` of the dependency. All my tests with elasticsearch work but with AWS OpenSearch I'm facing the same issue as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your OpenSearch to be running in compatibility mode. There is a flag during setup/creation which will enable this.

This can also be done via an API call:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "compatibility.override_main_response_version" : true
  }
}
```

Compatibility mode simply tells OpenSearch to report its elasticsearch version number back as being that of `7.10` instead of the 'newer' Opensearch `1.2.0` version.

This will allow your spark connector to correctly identify the version number and connect successfully.